# How to transition only rotate transformation?

Tags: css, rotation, transition

I'm using a bunch of elements to compose a background image and they all absolutely position around, rotating freely.

Problem is, I would like to transition only the rotation of those objects, not the top nor left properties. And apparently `transition: transform 30s;` isn't allowed. I had the brilliant idea of doing

```
transition:all 30s ease-out;
transition: left 0s;
transition: top 0s;
```

But that also doesn't work. How can I solve this?

Comment: transition transform IS allowed. What I guess is happening is that the center rotation is not where you expect. Anyway, is MY guess. May be better post a fiddle with your code.

Comment: Please post a fiddle.

Comment: I found where the problem was! I forgot to define the -webkit- prefix... How dumb! Thank you guys anyway!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Transform is a vendor prefix

Instead of

```
transition:all 30s ease-out;
transition: left 0s;
transition: top 0s;
```

do

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform $amount-of-time ease-out;
-moz-transition:    -moz-transform $amount-of-time ease-out;
-o-transition:      -o-transform $amount-of-time ease-out;
-ms-transition:     -ms-transform $amount-of-time ease-out;
transition:         transform $amount-of-time ease-out;
```

Comment: -ms-transition don't exist

Answer (score 18):

To animate only the rotate property, I found this works in at least Chrome:

```
transition: transform 2.0s;
```

You can set different animation times for different properties inside the one transition property:

```
transition: transform 2.0s, color 5.0s, font-size 1.0s;
```

The trick with the `rotate` property specifically is that you have use the `transform` property instead. Intuitively, this should work but does NOT work:

```
transition: rotate 2.0s; /* DOES NOT WORK */
```

Instead you have to use `transform` in place of `rotate`:

```
transition: transform 2.0s;
```

This is probably because `rotate: 90deg` is shorthand for `transform: rotate(90deg)`

#### Note

`transition` is now supported in the latest versions of all major browsers. I assume if you want more compatibility with older browsers, you might do something like:

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2.0s, color 5.0s, font-size 1.0s;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 2.0s, color 5.0s, font-size 1.0s;
-ms-transition: -ms-transform 2.0s, color 5.0s, font-size 1.0s;
-o-transition: -o-transform 2.0s, color 5.0s, font-size 1.0s;
transition: transform 2.0s, color 5.0s, font-size 1.0s;
```